# How to create a list of objects inside a for loop in Python without inherit attribute values

Tags: python, oop, arraylist

The code below creates a list of objects that contains a list as attribute and a method to append items to this list but this appending is not working like I expected.

**What I expected:**
Each list `MyList` inside of each object `MyObj` to have only 3 elements.

**How it is working:**
The list `MyList` inside of `MyObj[0]` has 3 elements
The list `MyList` inside of `MyObj[1]` has 6 elements
The list `MyList` inside of `MyObj[2]` has 9 elements

It seems to me the object `MyObj[i]` appends the `MyList` of prevous object `MyObj[i-1]`. How the code should be like to make each list `MyList` of each `MyObj[i]` have only the 3 elements inserted by the method `add_to_list`?

*Python code:*

```
class MyClass:
    MyList = []

    def add_to_list(self):

        for item in range(3):
            self.MyList.append("Item " + str(item))


MyObj = []

for i in range(3):
    MyObj.append(MyClass())
    MyObj[i].add_to_list()

    print("Object " + str(i))
    print(MyObj[i].MyList)
```

Comment: You can define MyList inside the init function in your class like this,
`class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.MyList = []`
Your main issue is you are using class variable MyList, which is shared among all objects of the same class, that's why it retains previous values. Defining it inside an init function and initializing it properly ensures it is unique for each object. Your question has already marked as a duplicate, so I can't post the answer in details. But I hope my comment helps you.

Comment: Thank you @Saeed. That was the solution for me

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to add a line of `MyObj[i].MyList.clear()`:

```
MyObj = []

for i in range(3):
    MyObj.append(MyClass())
    MyObj[i].add_to_list()

    print("Object " + str(i))
    print(MyObj[i].MyList)
    MyObj[i].MyList.clear()
```

Output:

```
Object 0
['Item 0', 'Item 1', 'Item 2']
Object 1
['Item 0', 'Item 1', 'Item 2']
Object 2
['Item 0', 'Item 1', 'Item 2']
```